# Couchdb 2.0 replicate multiple user databases to single db

Tags: couchdb-2.0

I am using couchdb and each user has their own database.

However, I have a web app that should be able to look up an _id in any database and return the document.  With thousands of users, querying across thousands of couchdb instances would be impractical.

How can I replicate my data to a single master database so that I can query by _id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing is replicating every userdb to a master db when the database was created, using the `_replicate` API endpoint.  The master db then contains a read-only copy of all the other databases.

Comment: UPDATE:  I've since discovered https://github.com/cloudant-labs/envoy which lets me use a single database and avoid replication.